# Проверка коммита на сервере GitLab Community

Tags: git, gitlab

Проблема в следующем: 
Заказчик использует GitLab Community в качестве git сервера. Надо запретить push на сервер коммитов, в которых коментарий не содержит номер таска из джиры (формат например: `#JIRA-1234`). В какую сторону копать?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Self-hosted или gitlab.com?

Comment: размещен Self-hosted

Comment: Дополнил про то, как всё это работает. Если будут вопросы — спрашивайте в комментариях к ответу, я получу уведомление о них.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), проверяющий сообщение коммита.

## Как написать хук `post-receive`

Полная инструкция с примерами есть [в документации git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy).

Кратко: хук получит на вход строку вроде

```
ab3c291835832c309 b2fed56890cab348 new-branch
```

В ней:

1. Хеш предыдущего коммита
2. Хеш нового коммита
3. Название ветки, которую вы запушили на сервер

Имея хеш нового коммита, вы можете получить его сообщение, чтобы проверить его регулярным выражением.

Если оно соответствует требованиям, хук должен вернуть `0`, если нет — `1`.

## Как установить его в GitLab

Для установки хука на сервер GitLab нужны права администратора.

Кратко:

1. Открыть директорию `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group>/<project>.git`
2. Создать в ней директорию  `custom_hooks/`
3. А в ней файл `pre-receive` (это полное имя, расширение не нужно.)
4. Выдайте этому файлу права на выполнение:

   ```
   chmod +x /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group>/<project>.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive
   ```
5. Содержимое этого файла — код на любом интерпретируемом языке (bash, python, ruby...), который есть в системе.

Подробная инструкция по установке в GitLab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html#setup

## Пример хука `post-receive`

Вот подходящий пример хука ([источник](https://gist.github.com/gortok/b204ac4997e9916ec6c6ef0987251530)). Есть также [статья](https://georgestocker.com/2017/01/04/how-do-i-require-specific-text-in-a-git-commit-message/) от автора хука, объясняющая его работу.

За проверку коммита отвечает вот эта строка:

```
match = re.search(r'TICKET-[0-9]{2,5}|#TICKET-[0-9]{2,5}|HOTFIX|FORCE', rev)
```

Соответственно, вам нужно её поменять так, чтобы вместо `TICKET` был буквенный код проекта в джире (явно это не `JIRA`).

Смысл `HOTFIX` и `FORCE` в том, что иногда бывают коммиты, не принадлежащие ни к какой задаче. Просто нашли ошибку и быстро исправили. Если не предусмотреть такие «волшебные слова», то придётся заводить по задаче на каждую опечатку в комментариях. Но и злоупотреблять ими тоже не нужно.

Код полностью:

```
#!/bin/python
import sys
import re
import subprocess


#Format: "oldref newref branch"
line = sys.stdin.read()
(base, commit, ref) = line.strip().split()
new_branch_push = re.match(r'[^1-9]+', base)
branch_deleted = re.match(r'[^1-9]+', commit)
contains_commit_msg = False
if not new_branch_push:
    revs = base + "..." + commit
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-list','--oneline','--first-parent', revs], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    lines = proc.stdout.readlines()
    if lines:
        for line in lines:
            rev = str(line)
            match = re.search(r'TICKET-[0-9]{2,5}|#TICKET-[0-9]{2,5}|HOTFIX|FORCE', rev)
            if match is not None:
                contains_commit_msg = True
if contains_commit_msg or new_branch_push or branch_deleted:
    exit(0)
else:
    print "Commit does not contain the story associated with the commit in the format: TICKET-123 or #TICKET-123"
exit(1)
```

Comment: Я так понял, что мне нужен доступ непосредсвенно в каталог с установленным  кастомерским GitLab? А можно ли как-то этот хук залить на мой тестовый GitLab, который размещен непосредственно на gitlab.com?

Comment: @HennadyKharkhasov неа, на gitlab.com нельзя получить доступ к файловой системе. Наверняка это сделано для безопасности — в коде хука ведь может быть что угодно.

Comment: @HennadyKharkhasov вы можете поднять гитлаб у себя на машине и потренироваться на нём. Либо создайте тестовый репозиторий в гитлабе заказчика и проверьте работу хука на нём. В любом случае для завершения задачи вам или кому-то ещё понадобится залезть прямо на сервер с гитлабом, причем наверняка с sudo-правами.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы подтвердили мои опасения=)

Comment: @HennadyKharkhasov что же там за опасения такие? )

Comment: Опасения что нужны полные права, а у нас большой проект и кастомеры "неместные" и могут возникнуть трудности с доступом=)

Comment: @HennadyKharkhasov, если те ваши люди, у кого есть право «пушить» на сервер заказчика, достаточно дисциплинированы, и надо лишь оградиться от ненамеренных ошибок, то локальных «хуков» (в клонах репозитория у этих людей) будет более чем достаточно. есть и [какие-то вспомогательные средства](http://stackoverflow.com/q/427207/4827341) для этого.

Comment: Рассматривал вариант, чтобы хранит ьхуки в репо, но тогда каждому сотруднику надо будет выполнить настройку по подклчению папки с хуками для проекта, но так как проект большой, то это не самый лучший способ для нас.

Comment: после добавления custom hook не забудьте про chmod +x /путь/к/файлу. Пол дня потерял...

Comment: @HennadyKharkhasov спасибо, я дополнил ответ.